# Bash: for loop, copy, backup

Tags: bash, loops, backup, for-loop, cp

Hey, not 100% sure what this error means.

```
% for f in "*" ; do cp $f ../backup/backup$f ; done
cp: ../backup/backup* not found
```

The purpose is to copy all the files into a folder into a backup folder and rename the files to backup.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `*` shouldn't be in quotes:

```
for f in * ; do cp $f ../backup/$f ; done
```

When you use quotes this prevents the shell from expanding it, so it is looking for a file called `*`, not all files in the directory which is what you meant.

Answer (score 7):

You are quoting the wrong things: quote the variables, not the wildcards!

`% for f in *; do cp "$f" "../backup/$f" ; done`

BTW, in this case, you can simply do:

`% cp * ../backup/`

Answer (score 3):

Or may be this:

```
cp -b * ../backup
```

If you want them to be renamed:

```
% for f in * ; do cp "$f" "../backup/${f}-backup" ; done
```